# WSO2 DAS Spark script fails to execute

Tags: apache-spark, wso2, apache-spark-sql, wso2-das

Following is the spark script I'm trying to execute. It's run succesefuly on DAS(3.0.1) Batch analytics console. But fails to execute when saved as a script in batch analytics.

```
insert overwrite table CLASS_COUNT select  ((timestamp / 120000) * 120000) as time , vin , username , classType,        
sum(acceleCount) as acceleCount , sum(decceleCount) as decceleCount
from ACCELE_COUNTS
group by ((timestamp / 120000) * 120000) ,classType, vin, username;
```

Error:

```
ERROR: [1.199] failure: ``limit'' expected but identifier ACCELE_COUNTSgroup found insert overwrite table X1234_CLASS_COUNT select ((timestamp / 120000) * 120000) as time , vin , username , classType, sum(acceleCount) as acceleCount , sum(decceleCount) as decceleCountfrom ACCELE_COUNTSgroup by ((timestamp / 120000) * 120000) ,classType, vin, username ^
```

Prior to this I'm executing following without any issue.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ACCELE_COUNTS 
USING CarbonAnalytics 
OPTIONS (tableName "KAMPANA_RECKLESS_COUNT_STREAM", 
     schema "timestamp LONG , vin STRING, username STRING, classType STRING, acceleCount INT,decceleCount INT");

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CLASS_COUNT 
USING org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.event.EventStreamProvider 
OPTIONS (receiverURL "tcp://localhost:7611",
     username "admin",
     password "admin",
     streamName "DAS_RECKELSS_COUNT_STREAM", 
     version "1.0.0",
     description "Events are published  when product quantity goes beyond a certain level",
     nickName "product alerts",
     payload "time LONG,vin STRING,username STRING, classType STRING, acceleCount INT, decceleCount INT"
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens as you don't have spaces between

1) `decceleCount` and `from`

2) `ACCELE_COUNTS` AND `group by`

So, make sure to have spaces between words even when the 2nd word is in a new line.